# Background Color Behind Navifgaion

Tags: css, web, navigation

I just had a quick question in regards to an issue I am trying to solve. I made my top navigation menu's background color transparent and for some reason there is some white background or something behind it so the image does not show through.

The website is http://jobspark.ca/. If someone can figure out what is causing this that would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in site.css you having the css for body like this.this is why you having background color as white and margin top as 80px...you can this two code as u want to change...if you remove the margin-top css you having nav to the top...

```
body {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: none;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
    color: #000000;
}

body {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```